# Visual basic (.net) Insert new record question

Tags: vb.net

i am a novice, trying to add a new record to a php myadmin database, the secondDB requires an "Id" to be inserted with the data.

the rest of the project uses data bound fileds.

so i generate the new record with

```
FirstDB.addnew()
secondDB.addnew()
```

then try to run the below

```
Call Connection() 'this gets My.Settings.companyConnectionString and opens the connection

Dim str As String = ("SELECT max(Id) FROM FirstDB")
cmd = New MySqlCommand(str, conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar +1 'this will get the number and increase by one

            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                With cmd
                    .CommandText = "insert into SecondDB(`id`) values (@id)"
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", result)

                End With

            End Using

            conn.Dispose()
```

also tryed

```
DataSet.Secondtable.Id.DefaulValue = result
SecondDBbindingSource.Current.item("Id") = result
```

the secondBD refuses to save without the missing "ID".

if you put the resut in a data bound box it works out fine, but i dont want to have text boxes scatterd around.

can anyone give me some guideance ?

Comment: it generates the firstDB ID (primary key) & the secondDB ID(Primary Key) but it also requires the primery key from the FirstDB as a link
-confuseing ! - 
you cant get this ID untill your first save or if you run the GETID request otherwise it returns a -1 and wont save

Comment: `FirstDB.addnew()` This looks like VBA in the last century with DAO. If this ID is the primary Key of one of the tables, why is it not auto-increment?

Comment: I think this might be a primary Key / foreign key thing. You can get the last inserted id in MySql with SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); but in a multiuser environment this is not reliable unless in a transaction with the insert.

Comment: @mary theres two sets of ID and one link-ID, both sets of primary ID auto increment, the Link ID is there to keep the relasionship, the FirstDB.add new is a little old but works well for a novice like me

Answer (score 0):

```
FirstDB.addnew()
secondDB.addnew()
```

I have no idea what this code is doing.

```
Call Connection()
```

Don't do this. Connections need to be declared and disposed in the method where they are used. Using blocks take care of this for us even it there is an error.

```
 Dim str As String = ("SELECT max(Id) FROM FirstDB")
```

This is not a good way to find the Id you are looking for. In MySql you can add `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` to the Insert for FirstDB (terrible name for a table). In a multi-user environment Max will fail.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

The default type for a command is the Text type so you don't have to explicitly set this property. Interesting that you don't set this property when you create a new command a few lines down.

```
Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar + 1
```

`ExecuteScalar` returns an `Object`. You cannot add one to an `Object`. Why do you want to increment this value? The foreign key in secondDB should match the primary key in FirstDB. You said in comments both tables have a primary key field that is auto increment.

```
.CommandText = "insert into SecondDB(`id`) values (@id)"
```

Is that all you are entering into the new record? Not a very informative record.

```
conn.Dispose()
```

What if an error occurred. Your connection would never be closed or disposed.

```
DataSet.Secondtable.Id.DefaulValue = result
SecondDBbindingSource.Current.item("Id") = result
```

I have no idea what you are doing here.

I have to make up a table structure for the 2 tables (not DB, tables).

```
Private Sub OPCode(Company As String, Contact As String, Address As String)
    Dim IdFromFirstDB As Integer
    Dim sql = "Insert Into FirstDB (CompanyName, ContactName) Values (@Name, @Contact) Select LAST_INSERT_ID();"
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.companyConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = Company
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Contact", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Contact
            cn.Open()
            IdFromFirstDB = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
        sql = "Insert Into secondDb (Address, CompanyID) Values (@Address, @ID);"
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = Address
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = IdFromFirstDB
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: to anser some of the questions asked above the two add new to sart a new record on the data bound side - i get the idea is bad to try and mix databound and mysql inserts in to the same project. - unless theres a more effective way of puting the ID in i may be forced to use bound textboxes `Public Sub Connection() conn = New MySqlConnection With conn              .ConnectionString = My.Settings.companyConnectionString .Open() End With End Sub 
the GETID then would close / dispose

Comment: would puting a close / dispose in a execption deail with errors that dont close or dispose of the connection

Comment: Structured exception handling has a Finally section that is always executed. Yes, it can make a mess to combine databound controls and manually updating databases. Not sure what GETID is but just keep you connection local to the method where they are used. As you can see a single line creates and initializes the connection and `End Using` closes and disposes even if there is an error.

Comment: GETID is is the code above `Dim str As String = ("SELECT max(Id) FROM FirstDB")
cmd = New MySqlCommand(str, conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar +1`
-Question if i added a finally to the connection as above would that be good enough? - second question do i have to remove the first dispose ?

Comment: I don't know why you are so resistant to doing it the Using blocks. If you are disposing in the Finally a dispose within the Try block would be redundant. It may cause an NRE in the Finally . Exceptions in a Finally should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: so : ` Public Sub GETID()
        Call Connection()

        Try
            Dim str As String = ("SELECT max(Id) FROM FirstDB")
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(str, conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            MintId = cmd.ExecuteScalar + 1
      
            form1.Id.Text = MintId


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("An error was encountered" &
        vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message))

        Finally
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub`

Comment: is better for sanity ? If your not useing mysql : SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: Tacking it on after the Insert gives you a better chance of getting the correct ID in a multiuser environment.

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: @AndrewSadler I did in my answer.